# In EC2 not able to curl localhost, using wildfly swarm

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, tcp, port, wildfly-swarm

I have a wildfly swarm app running in a docker container in Amazon EC2.

Here is my Docker ps:

```
913171ca1a34        xxxxxxxxxxx/myrepository:osapp2.0   "java -jar /app/Or..."   55 minutes ago      Up 55 minutes       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4000->80/tcp   elastic_yonath

netstat -ano | grep 4000 gives following output
tcp        0      0 :::4000                     :::*                        LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

 netstat -ano | grep 80
udp        0      0 fe80::841:a6ff:fe76:c70c:546 :::*                                    off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 :::53880                    :::*                                    off (0.00/0/0)
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9800
```

I have enabled Port 80 in security Group in my EC2 in inbound

I have removed `::1` from the `/etc/hosts` file based on other entires in the StackOverflow.

I am getting when using curl:

```
"curl http://locahost:4000"
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

"curl http://localhost:8080"
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I am able to run my docker in my local system.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my IPtables:

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT

-P FORWARD DROP

-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

-N DOCKER

-N DOCKER-ISOLATION

-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION

-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER

-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
```

i did a netstat -antp, here the port is listed like an IPV6 address ? How can i run my docker with IPV4 configuration

sudo netstat -antp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address
State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2294/rpcbind

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2481/sshd

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2511/sendmail

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51501               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      2315/rpc.statd

tcp        0    300 172.30.1.61:22              202.60.62.100:39334         ESTABLISHED 4539/sshd

tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      2294/rpcbind

tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2481/sshd

tcp        0      0 :::36475                    :::*                        LISTEN      2315/rpc.statd

tcp        0      0 :::4000                     :::*                        LISTEN      4431/docker-proxy

Comment: Are you really using `http:\localhost`?  You know it's `http://localhost`, right?

Comment: Yes i was using http://locahost, but before this posting to get the error message again, i made a mistake by using http:\\locahost. I have updated the correct error message in my post now. Thanks for catching the same.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/769578/curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-when-hitting-docker-container This is relevant for my issue. I am able to curl inside my container. But i dont understand the solution listed here.

Comment: docker exec -it d86aed3df80e bash then curl http://localhost:8080/rest/orderapp?ordernumber=101&&offset=1, I am able to access my service.

Comment: this the docker run command for the above line docker run -d -p 8080:80 raxxxxx/myrepository:osapp3.0

Answer (score 0):

This link showed me a way
"https://serverfault.com/questions/769578/curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-when-hitting-docker-container"

I was able to connect to docker bash and was able to curl the url

so i did two things
1) In my Maven POM.xml i added a configuration to set a 0.0.0.0
or 
2) I could have passed the bind address in my entry point tag in the docker file

Then i used port 8080 in docker run command

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 rajxxxxxx/myrepository:osapp3.0

now i am able to curl " http://localhost:8080/rest/orderapp?ordernumber=102&&offset=1" in EC2